# Initializing enum in java using gson

Tags: java, json, enums, gson

Consider the following code

```
public class MyClass {
    public static enum MyEnum {
        ENUM_A("This is a"), ENUM_B("This is b");
        private String desc;
        private MyEnum(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }
        public String getDesc() { return desc; }
    }
    private String someString;
    private Integer someInteger;
    public MyClass(String string, Integer integer) {
        this.someString = string;
        this.someInteger = integer;
    }
}
```

I want to use a json file to initialize the desc for the enums of **MyEnum**. I started by printing out the json string of an instance of **MyClass** but the string has nothing about **MyEnum**, only values for *someString* and *someInteger*. Apparently **MyEnum** is not being deserialized, so I dont even know if **MyEnum** can be serialized by gson.

Could you provide example on how to initialize the desc for the enums of **MyEnum** while creating a **MyClass** instance via MyClass c = gson.fromJson(string, MyClass.class), or directly initialize **MyEnum** via MyEnum e = gson.fromJson(string, MyEnum.class).

Since MyEnum is static, what would happen after running the above code? Does the other code that use MyEnum now pick up the new desc?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any field for `MyEnum` at `MyClass`. You only have a declaration of an enum type. So it's very normal to get `someString` and `someInteger` values after serialization.

Add a field for MyEnum to your MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static enum MyEnum {
        ENUM_A("This is a"), ENUM_B("This is b");
        private String desc;
        private MyEnum(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }
        public String getDesc() { return desc; }
    }
    private String someString;
    private Integer someInteger;
    private MyEnum myEnum; // Add a field for MyEnum

    public MyClass(String string, Integer integer) {
        this.someString = string;
        this.someInteger = integer;

        this.myEnum = MyEnum.ENUM_A; // initialized myEnum with ENUM_A for demo.
    }
}
```

Now try below code:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    MyClass instance1 = new MyClass("str", 1);        
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(instance1));
```

**Output:**

> `{"myEnum":"ENUM_A","someInteger":1,"someString":"str"}`

As you see serialization is done successfully. Now try to deserialize:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = "{\"myEnum\":\"ENUM_A\",\"someInteger\":1,\"someString\":\"str\"}";
    MyClass instance2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);

    System.out.println("myEnum: " + instance2.myEnum);
    System.out.println("myEnum.desc: " + instance2.myEnum.getDesc());
```

**Output:**

> myEnum: ENUM_A 
>   myEnum.desc: This is a

**Edit:**

You defined an enum named as MyEnum, and it has a value such as ENUM_A("This is a"), and you want to change this value's desc programmatically from "This is a" to "A for apple", is that correct? If so it is impossible with enums because they are initialized at compile time and can not be changed at runtime. You can read about `Enum.valueOf` method, the desc part will make more sense after understanding valueOf method. Also for your 'another question', I guess you have misunderstanding on static classes and static fields

Comment: Thanks for this but thats not what I want. I actually only want to initialize MyEnum. i.e. I want to read from a json string to set the desc in MyEnum, so that after deserializing, MyEnum becomes ENUM_A("A for apple", ENUM_B("B for boy"). Followed up with another question, whether I can actually re-initialize an enum and what happens to other code that is already using the enum, do they get updated to use the new enum desc (as the enum is static).

Comment: You defined an enum named as MyEnum, and it has a value such as ENUM_A("This is a"), and you want to change this value's desc programmatically from "This is a" to "A for apple", is that correct? If so it is impossible with enums because they are initialized at compile time and can not be changed at runtime. You can read about Enum.valueOf method, the desc part will make more sense after understanding valueOf method. Also for your 'another question', I guess you have misunderstanding on static classes and static fields.

Comment: Thanks again. So yes, thats what I actually want: a json configurable enum class. As your current answer is not related to what I really asked, could you please update it with the new answer (i.e. impossibility of doing enum configuration) so that I can check yours as the answer.